# Old owner deleted all applications including install.app and now I cant do anything

Tags: leopard, powerpc

I can't open any .pkg files because install.app is gone and I dont have any install media because it wasnt originally my Mac. Pls help I just want to get 10.5.8 running

iMac6,3

Comment: Which version of macOS are you currently running?

Comment: @nohillside I am currently running 10.4.11. Wikipedia says I should be able to get up to 1.5.8 running. If I could even get a clean install of my current version that would be awesome.

Comment: You need to do a clean install. Both Leopard (10.5) and Tiger (10.4) are available on eBay for nominal amounts of money, or can be downloaded from Mac abandonware websites.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy man I was worried it was gonna come to that. I'm just a kid with little disposable income and my only other computer is windows.

Comment: @LanarJ "or can be downloaded from Mac abandonware websites." 

Comment: Archive.org has [several Leopard Install DVD images](https://archive.org/search.php?query=os%20x%20leopard). 9A343 is a beta-test build, so you don't want that, but there seem to be two drop-in DVD images (part #2Z691-6040-A) which IIRC is what Apple "dropped into" computers that had been manufactured but not sold when 10.5 came out, so it should work. Then download & install the [10.5.8 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL866) and then [security update 2012-003](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1533).

Comment: @DavidAnderson It sounds like OP has a PPC Mac (question tag + statement that Leopard is the maximum). That rules out Windows (and Snow Leopard).